# AND Operator in While Loop

Tags: vb.net, while-loop, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I don't want my loop to end until both conditions are met. I am using the AND operator but if -1 gets put in any one of the texts boxes the program exits which I don't want. I clearly want -1 to be entered in BOTH text boxes before it exits. Any guidance in where I am going wrong will be greatly appreciated.

```
While Not ((U) = "-1" And Not (P) = "-1")

    "Statements"    

    End While
```

It's seems to be acting like an OR.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you got an extra `Not` operator. Try this instead:

```
While Not (U = "-1" And P = "-1")

"Statements"    

End While
```

Notice that **I also dropped the extra parentheses** around `U` and `P`. They're not required and will only make your condition harder to read.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `Not` next to the `And`. Change it to this.

```
While Not ((U) = "-1" And (P) = "-1")

"Statements"    

End While
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use AndAlso to take advantage of short circuting.

```
While U <> "-1" AndAlso P <> "-1"
    'Statemements
End While
```